# Issue in uninstalling product with custom ui other than maintenance mode

Tags: user-interface, wix, installation, uninstallation

Currently we are trying to uninstall product from the custom UI (without maintaincetypedlg window) in WIX installer.

We uninstall the existing product with the latest version from the custom UI with the command "WixUI_InstallMode =Remove" in Pushbutton

```
<Control Id="RemoveButton" Type="PushButton" X="40" Y="140" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Uninstall">

<Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="Remove">1</Publish>

<Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>

</Control> </code>
```

But VerifyReadyDlg does not show the remove button instead it shows install button.
(Note: It shows the remove button and then it replaced by Install button when we mousehover on the Remove button)

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Code is very hard to read. Please [reformat as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0):

By adding the below mentioned tag

`<Publish Property="Installed" Value="true">1</Publish>`

Thanks